# Deploy Windows Server from Puppet

Tags: windows, puppet, devops, windows-server-2012-r2

I am looking into learning Puppet specifically deploy Windows Server via Puppet, can anyone point me to the right direction like docs, ebook that i need to go through in order to deploy VM's.

I was looking into Puppet website, but i wasn't sure from where should i start. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: By “deploy” do you mean bare metal provisioning?

Comment: yes similiar to Azure Deployment which can be done via Javascript

Comment: Then [razor](https://github.com/puppetlabs/razor-server) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Windows deployment using puppet is very similar to linux puppet deployment because finally you're defining resources (you don't care about the os).
Puppet's documentation is good to start:
https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/type.html
And maybe you would have to take a look into some interesting modules for windows as:
https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/powershell
https://forge.puppet.com/chocolatey/chocolatey